# Why attachPatternMatched not working in first load if it is put in onAfterRendering?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I am using `echarts` in my UI5 App, so I need to wait dom ready and then execute `_onObjectMatched`, but in first load, `_onObjectMatched` is triggered if I put it in `onInit`, but it is not working in `onAfterRendering`. I put a log in onAfterRendering, so I am pretty sure onAfterRendering is executed, and the later call of `_onObjectMatched` is OK. BTW, I am building a Master-Detail Page.

```
onInit : function () {
   this.getRouter().getRoute("object").attachPatternMatched(this._onObjectMatched, this);
}

onAfterRendering: function () {
   this.getRouter().getRoute("object").attachPatternMatched(this._onObjectMatched, this);
}

getRouter : function () {
    return sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The route is matched after `onInit()` but before `onAfterRendering()`. So if you attach your eventhandler in `onAfterRendering()` you are simply too late and miss the event.

I would recommend to attach your handler in `onInit()` and save the route information in the controller if your echart is not ready.
Use that information after your echart has been initialized to update your view.

```js
onAfterRendering:function(){
  //init charts
  this._chartReady = true;
  this._updateViewFromRoute();
},
onBeforeRendering:function(){
  this._chartReady = false;
},
_onObjectMatched:function(oEvent){
  //Save Args
  this._routerArgs = oEvent.getParameter("arguments");
  this._updateViewFromRoute();
},
_updateViewFromRoute:function(){
  if(!this._chartReady) return;
  if(!this._routerArgs) return;
  //do something with this._routerArgs
  this._routerArgs = null;
}
```